# Why does 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' not popup when testing through browser?

Tags: angular, http

I am trying to access the github jobs api data with my webapp, when I call https://jobs.github.com/positions.json in my browser I receive usable data. Whenever I do a get request through my Angular 5 application I get the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' error.

I don't understand why I am able to lookup data through my browser, and not throug my Angular application. As far as I understand, I need to register the url that I am using for my application (in this case localhost:4000). What is my so called origin when I lookup something in my browser?

Is there a possibility to lookup what URLs are allowed?

Comment: You need to bypass this restriction in your angular 5 application somehow, This restriction comes from angular itself

Comment: Quick analogy why these security measures are implemented, why are you able to access gmail (or any other site)  using your browser, and not using a script on any foreign site